# What files are generated by Xcode when compiling and linking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, svn, xcode, mercurial

Since I'm used to developing in Java, I'm familiar with what files get generated by the build process and can tell what files to exclude from SVN and HG when I do comits.

I'm just starting out learning some iOS app building using XCode.  With XCode and Objective-C on a Mac, I don't know what files get generated.  If there are files specific to the iOS development situation, I'd like to know those files as well.

What files, extensions or otherwise, should I add to a .hgignore file or svn:ignore to properly keep generated files out of my code repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your generally ok if you exclude the build folder in your xcode project.

Comment: I also ignore *.pbxuser and *.mode1v3 since those are per-user preferences (they're in the *.xcodeproj package/directory)

Answer (score 7):

Here's the default .hgignore file that I copy into each Cocoa project I make.

```
syntax: glob
.DS_Store
build
.svn
(*)
*.pbxuser
*.perspectivev3
*.mpkg
*.framework
*.app
```

Hope this helps!